# Update Google Charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-visualization

I am developing an application, I have some data in CSV format and I want to show them in a line chart using Google Visualization API, I send my data with JSON to my view and show it to the chart:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
results = [];

google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8081/petclinic/users/7/campaigns/2/queries/4/analyze", function(data){
        for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
                data[i][1] =parseInt(data[i][1]);
        }

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
        var options = {
          title: 'Data Analysis'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    });
});
</script>
```

This works correctly, now I want to add other data to this chart, for example, if I click on a button the data should be updated with new info and another line chart should be drawn to be able to compare them.

Here is an example: for example in the beginning this is my data which is shown:

```
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                                                           ['Date', 'Obama'],
                                                           ['07/05/2004',  1000],
                                                           ['08/05/2004',  1170],
                                                           ['09/05/2004',  660],
                                                           ['10/05/2004',  1030],
                                                           ['11/05/2004',  1030],
                                                           ['12/05/2004',  1030],
                                                           ['13/05/2004',  1030],
                                                         ]);
```

Then I want to add other data to this chart like this:

```
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                                                           ['Date', 'Obama', 'Romney'],
                                                           ['07/05/2004',  1000,      400],
                                                           ['08/05/2004',  1170,      460],
                                                           ['09/05/2004',  660,       1120],
                                                           ['10/05/2004',  1030,      540],
                                                           ['11/05/2004',  1030,      540],
                                                           ['12/05/2004',  1030,      540],
                                                           ['13/05/2004',  1030,      540],
                                                         ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can go about doing this:

1. If you know all the data during the initial transaction where you send the CSV data, you can populate all the data in the `DataTable`, and use a [`DataView`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView) to only view some of the columns. When you want to display the additional columns, the easiest thing to do is to create a new `DataView`, and redraw the chart.
2. If you don't know the data, and need to do a second call to the server to get the new data, once the data is returned, you can add the new data to the [`DataTable`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable) with the `addColumn` function, and then use `setCell` for every item. Then just call `draw` on the chart again. (I've filed a feature request to have `addColumn` accept an array to make this easier.)

Incidentally, I've also filed a feature request to accept CSV files directly in `DataTable`. Obviously, I make no promises when/if any of these feature requests will get done.